# is there any book for aps.net MVC Social Networking Website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, social-networking

I am new to Asp.net MVC, i want to study social networking websites. so is there any good tutorial or book.i have read  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/332173/Parichay but its not enough for a new learner like me.
Thanks

Comment: Requests for off-site documentation are offtopic for SO. If you want to learn C# first, pick up a C# book. Then an ASP.NET MVC book and then you're on your own, as there's little proper information out there how to write a specific kind of application using any kind of framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't know of any good material for you to read, it seems a bit too specific. But I do have some advice that might get you started.

Since you are new to asp.net MVC and your goal is to create some sort of social networking website, I would recommend just starting to code. Just start small with what you already know. Like; you need to authenticate the users, they need a profile and a way to edit it, they will be posting some sort of status updates and so on. This kind of try and fail iteration approach will give you so much more in terms of knowledge, experience and insight both to asp.net MVC and to how social networking works in general.

I'm not saying tutorials are bad, but I think a balanced combination is the best. So taking pieces from different tutorials on http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials or other places in order to get authentication and profile editing working i.e.

Hope this is somewhat helpful to you even though I could not directly help you with your question.

Comment: Oh, I'm new to stackoverflow, I thought this would be a comment, but I see I don't have enough points for commenting and that I posted this as an answer, which it obviously is not. I'll let it stay there if that's ok. Guess I need to level up some in order to comment on the question.